# Null Values during Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select, stored-procedures, join

I have the below table, pretty simple.

```
==========================================================================
attendanceID   |   agentID   |   incurredDate   |   points   |   comment
==========================================================================
    10         |  vimunson   |    2013-07-22    |     2      | Some Text
    11         |  vimunson   |    2013-07-29    |     2      | Some Text
    12         |  vimunson   |    2013-12-06    |     1      | Some Text
```

The his query below:

```
SELECT 
    attendanceID,
    agentID,
    incurredDate,
    leadDate,
    points,
    @1F:=IF(incurredDate <= curdate() - 90
            AND leadDate = NULL,
        points - 1,
        IF(DATEDIFF(leadDate, incurredDate) > 90,
            points - 1,
            points)) AS '1stFallOff',
    @2F:=IF(incurredDate <= curdate() - 180
            AND leadDate = NULL,
        points - 2,
        IF(DATEDIFF(leadDate, incurredDate) > 180,
            points - 2,
            @1F)) AS '2ndFallOff',
    IF(@total < 0, 0, @total:=@total + @2F) AS Total,
    comment,
    linked
FROM
    (SELECT 
        attendanceID,
            mo.agentID,
            @r AS leadDate,
            (@r:=incurredDate) AS incurredDate,
            comment,
            points,
            linked
    FROM
        (SELECT 
        m . *
    FROM
        (SELECT @_date = NULL, @total:=0) varaible, attendance m
    ORDER by agentID , incurredDate desc) mo
    where
        agentID = 'vimunson'
            AND (case
            WHEN @_date is NULL or @_date <> incurredDate THEN @r:=NULL
            ELSE NULL
        END IS NULL)
            AND (@_date:=incurredDate) IS NOT NULL) T
ORDER BY agentID , incurredDate
```

When I run the query it returns the below:

```
========================================================================================================================================
attendanceID   |   agentID   |   incurredDate   |   leadDate   |   points   |   1stFallOff   |   2ndFallOff   |   Total   |   comment
========================================================================================================================================
   10          |  vimunson   |   2013-07-22     |     NULL     |     2      |       2        |       2        |     2     |   Some Text
   11          |  vimunson   |   2013-07-29     |     NULL     |     2      |       2        |       2        |     4     |   Some Text
   12          |  vimunson   |   2013-12-06     |     NULL     |     1      |       2        |       1        |     5     |   Some Text
```

I cannot figure out why the `leadDate` column is `null'. I have narrowed it down to a user session. For example if I run it again with the same user session it will come back with what I want.

Comment: It's only one time null for me. Is this your desired result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6f0ac/3/0 ?

Comment: Yes, the `leadDate` is null the first time in the same user session. But if I am in the same user and run it again it will give me my desired result.

Comment: So why does this not work when I run it on the server but runs fine on sqlfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing multiple results I was able to come up with something that is what I expect. I have entered more data and the below syntax. I liked the idea of the cursor but it was not ideal for my use, so I did not use it. I did not want to use `CASE` or any `JOINS` since they can be complex.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2fb86/1

```
SELECT 
    attendanceID,
    agentID,
    incurredDate,
    @ld:=(select 
            incurredDate
        from
            attendance
        where
            incurredDate > a.incurredDate
                and agentID = a.agentID
        order by incurredDate
        limit 1) leadDate,
    points,
    @1F:=IF(incurredDate <= DATE_SUB(curdate(),
            INTERVAL IF(incurredDate < '2013-12-02', 90, 60) DAY)
            AND @ld <=> NULL,
        points - 1,
        IF(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(@ld, '1900-01-01'),
                    incurredDate) > IF(incurredDate < '2013-12-02', 90, 60),
            points - 1,
            points)) AS '1stFallOff',
    @2F:=IF(incurredDate <= DATE_SUB(curdate(),
            INTERVAL IF(incurredDate < '2013-12-02',
                180,
                120) DAY)
            AND getLeadDate(incurredDate, agentID) <=> NULL,
        points - 1,
        IF(DATEDIFF(COALESCE(@ld, '1900-01-01'),
                    incurredDate) > IF(incurredDate < '2013-12-02',
                180,
                120),
            points - 2,
            @1F)) AS '2ndFallOff',
    IF((@total + @2F) < 0,
        0,
        IF(DATE_ADD(incurredDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) <= CURDATE(),
            @total:=0,
            @total:=@total + @2F)) AS Total,
    comment,
    linked,
    DATE_ADD(incurredDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) AS 'fallOffDate'
FROM
    (SELECT @total:=0) v,
    attendance a
WHERE
    agentID = 'vimunson'
GROUP BY agentID , incurredDate
```

Answer (score 1):

The way variables `@r` and `@_date` are passed around relies on a specific order in which certain parts of the query are evaluated. That's a risky assumption to make in a query language that is declarative rather than imperative. The more sophisticated a query optimizer is, the more unpredictable the behaviour of this query will be. A 'simple' engine might follow your intentions, another engine might adapt its behaviour as you go, for example because it uses temporary indexes to improve query performance.

In situations where you need to pass values from one row to another, it would be better to use a cursor.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cursors.html

**EDIT:** sample code below.

I focused on column 'leadDate'; implementation of the falloff and total columns should be similar.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyProc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE done int DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE currentAttendanceID int;
    DECLARE currentAgentID, previousAgentID varchar(8);
    DECLARE currentIncurredDate date;
    DECLARE currentLeadDate date;
    DECLARE currentPoints int;
    DECLARE currentComment varchar(9);
    DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT attendanceID, agentID, incurredDate, points, comment
        FROM attendance
        ORDER BY agentID, incurredDate DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTemp (
        attendanceID int,
        agentID varchar(8),
        incurredDate date,
        leadDate date,
        points int,
        comment varchar(9)
    ) ENGINE=MEMORY;

    OPEN myCursor;

    SET previousAgentID := NULL;

    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH myCursor INTO currentAttendanceID, currentAgentID, currentIncurredDate, currentPoints, currentComment;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        IF previousAgentID IS NULL OR previousAgentID <> currentAgentID THEN
            SET currentLeadDate := NULL;
            SET previousAgentID := currentAgentID;
        END IF;
        INSERT INTO myTemp VALUES (currentAttendanceID, currentAgentID, currentIncurredDate, currentLeadDate, currentPoints, currentComment);
        SET currentLeadDate := currentIncurredDate;
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE myCursor;

    SELECT *
    FROM myTemp
    ORDER BY agentID, incurredDate;

    DROP TABLE myTemp;
END
```

FYC: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/910a3/1/0

Comment: would it be possible to provide an example of how you would make this happen? I see the logic behind cursor but for some reason it is not clicking.

Comment: Thanks a million @Ruud, after working on this for so long I am able to finish this part of the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.attendanceID, a.agentID, a.incurredDate, a.leadDate, a.points, 
       @1F:= (CASE WHEN incurredDate <= CURDATE()-90 AND leadDate=NULL THEN points-1 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(leadDate, incurredDate) > 90 THEN points-1 
                   ELSE points 
              END) AS '1stFallOff',
       @2F:= (CASE WHEN incurredDate <= CURDATE()-180 AND leadDate=NULL THEN points-2 
                   WHEN DATEDIFF(leadDate, incurredDate) > 180 THEN points-2 
                   ELSE @1F 
              END) AS '2ndFallOff',
     (@Total:=@Total + a.points) AS Total, a.comment 
FROM (SELECT a.attendanceID, a.agentID, a.incurredDate, b.incurredDate leadDate, a.points, a.comment 
      FROM attendance a 
      LEFT JOIN attendance b ON a.agentID = b.agentID AND a.incurredDate < b.incurredDate 
      GROUP BY a.agentID, a.incurredDate
     ) AS A, (SELECT @Total:=0, @1F:=0, @2F:=0) B;
```

Check the [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5cde5/4)

**OUTPUT**

```
| ATTENDANCEID |  AGENTID |                    INCURREDDATE |                        LEADDATE | POINTS | 1STFALLOFF | 2NDFALLOFF | TOTAL |   COMMENT |
|--------------|----------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|--------|------------|------------|-------|-----------|
|           10 | vimunson |     July, 22 2013 00:00:00+0000 |     July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      2 |          2 |          2 |     2 | Some Text |
|           11 | vimunson |     July, 29 2013 00:00:00+0000 | December, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |      2 |          1 |          1 |     4 | Some Text |
|           12 | vimunson | December, 06 2013 00:00:00+0000 |                          (null) |      1 |          1 |          1 |     5 | Some Text |
```

Comment: Thanks for you time, but unfortunately `JOIN` produces unpredictable results and I need something that is able to give me consistent results over and over without error.

Comment: @BrandonWilson Where you find the unpredictable behavior of my query. Explain in detail or so me the result of your input date

Comment: I found the error, I was using `ORDER BY` instead of `GROUP BY`. Once I had that fixed the `total` column does not calculate that way its suppose to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5cde5/3/0

Comment: @BrandonWilson Check my updated answer. I had added three columns as you want. There is no need to use cursor. Using single SQL scripts you can achieve the target